# how to get likes counts from a Facebook page using Graph Explorer 2.4

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

While this question has been asked a lot, I've still haven't find a way to do it.
I'm passing this to Graph Api Explorer

```
40796308305/?fields=feed{full_picture,created_time,message,likes}
```

this gives me the, Picture to every status, created time , message - user status and **likes** which gives me array of data and users that likes the status.
i'm trying to get count of those users and remember there were a field 'summary' but I don't see it in the JSON Results. 
Am I missing something with 2.4 api version ? 
any help will be appreciate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to *request* the summary:

```
/40796308305/?fields=feed{full_picture,created_time,message,likes.summary(1)}
```

And if you are *only* interested in the total count, but not the individual users that liked, you might want to set the `limit` for likes to 0, so as not to request unnecessary data:

```
/40796308305/?fields=feed{full_picture,created_time,message,likes.limit(0).summary(1)}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. what you are suggesting is working and accepted is as an answer, but I'm wondering, Why it's not on the Docs of FB ? I tried to add it through Graph Explorer with the list and I can't find 'summary' there, Is that mean it's going to be deprecated ? just very odd Facebook make hard life for us to find it.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/object/likes: _“`total_count` […]. This is only returned when the flag `summary=true` is set.”_

Comment: thank you for the link, I've been there but it does giving example how to use it (like you gave me) since I need to put it in bundle and get an array and not only 1 object. anyway Thank you so much, it's working perfect now.

Comment: Well you have to combine it with the information about basic API use, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.4#fieldexpansion